# "Streets" in holdem

Tags: texas-hold-em, omaha

In hold-em style games (Texas holdem, Omaha) you commonly hear the turn being called "fourth street" and the river "fifth street".

Why is this? Is it because the turn is the 4th card on the board (and river 5th)?

Or does it refer to the betting rounds?

1. Blinds/antes
2. Preflop
3. Flop
4. Turn
5. River

Comment: do you have an example of when someone refers to the river as the 5th street? i have always heard it referred to as the 4th street.

Answer (score 2):

In stud games 4th and 5th street refer to the 4th and 5th cards in the player's hand and not to the 4th betting round, since it is the 2nd or 3rd betting round (I am not quite sure exactly, because of the bring in). Check out the definition of a street [here](https://www.pokernews.com/pokerterms/street.htm).

This term is used exclusively for stud games. In hold 'em type games I only ever heard about 1-3 streets of value. In hold 'em, streets are not named. Instead, we have flop, turn and river. The term used like this must have been wrongly carried over. Since the 4th street in stud games refers not to the 4th betting round, but to the 4th card, it can be concluded that those people use it in the same way for hold 'em type games.

Comment: +1 to the "3 streets of value" this is the context I hear it used most in also.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Stud variations, the small forced ante or just ante would be the first street.  The large forced bring in would be an automatic bet the low man would be forced to make and would be 2nd street.  Two cards down and one up would be the 3rd street of betting after the auto forced bring in is made.  Next card up would be 4th street.  The next card up would be 5th street.  The next card up would be 6th street.  And the last card down would be 7th street.  Some might consider it a bit of a stretch to consider the forced bring in as the 2nd street, but it is a unique betting requirement that does not apply to all players.  If anyone can make the betting rounds work better then please share.  Rob